# Poloniex api error while downloading data using python3

Tags: python, python-requests, python-3.5, poloniex

I am trying to run the [Speculator](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/speculator/0.2.7) library. While trying to run I came across the following error:

```
PC@PC:~/Speculator/speculator$ python3 main.py 
INFO:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): poloniex.com
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 92, in <module>
    raise SystemExit(main())
  File "main.py", line 59, in main
    count=args.count, period=args.period)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/speculator/market.py", line 48, in __init__
    self.json = self.get_json()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/speculator/market.py", line 59, in get_json
    self.period, self.symbol)[0]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/speculator/utils/poloniex.py", line 61, in chart_json
    json = requests.get(url).json()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 808, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py", line 319, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
```

The error what I think is coming from this code:

```
import logging
import requests
from speculator.utils import date

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def json_to_url(json, symbol):
    """ Converts a JSON to a URL by the Poloniex API 

    Args:
        json: JSON data as a list of dict dates, where the keys are
            the raw market statistics.
        symbol: String of currency pair, like a ticker symbol.

    Returns:
        String URL to Poloniex API representing the given JSON.
    """
    start = json[0]['date']
    end = json[-1]['date']
    diff = end - start

    # Get period by a ratio from calculated period to valid periods
    # Ratio closest to 1 is the period
    # Valid values: 300, 900, 1800, 7200, 14400, 86400
    periods = [300, 900, 1800, 7200, 14400, 86400]

    diffs = {}
    for p in periods:
        diffs[p] = abs(1 - (p / (diff / len(json)))) # Get ratio

    period = min(diffs, key=diffs.get) # Find closest period

    url = ('https://poloniex.com/public?command'
           '=returnChartData&currencyPair={0}&start={1}'
           '&end={2}&period={3}').format(symbol, start, end, period) 
    return url

def chart_json(start, end, period, symbol):
    """ Requests chart data from Poloniex API

    Args:
        start: Int epoch date to START getting market stats from.
            Note that this epoch is FURTHER from the current date.
        end: Int epoch date to STOP getting market stats from.
            Note that this epoch is CLOSER to the current date.
        period: Int defining width of each chart candlestick in seconds.
            Valid values: 300, 900, 1800, 7200, 14400, 86400
        symbol: String of currency pair, like a ticker symbol.

    Returns:
        Tuple of (JSON data, URL to JSON).
        JSON data as a list of dict dates, where the keys are
        the raw market statistics.
        String URL to Poloniex API representing the given JSON.
    """
    url = ('https://poloniex.com/public?command'
           '=returnChartData&currencyPair={0}&start={1}'
           '&end={2}&period={3}').format(symbol, start, end, period) 
    logger.debug(' HTTP Request URL:\n{0}'.format(url))
    json = requests.get(url).json()
    logger.debug(' JSON:\n{0}'.format(json))

    if 'error' in json:
        logger.error(' Invalid parameters in URL for HTTP response')
        raise SystemExit
    elif all(val == 0 for val in json[0]):
        logger.error(' Bad HTTP response.  Time unit too short?')
        raise SystemExit
    elif len(json) < 1: # time to short
        logger.error(' Not enough dates to calculate changes')
        raise SystemExit

    return json, url

def parse_changes(json):
    """ Gets price changes from JSON

    Args:
        json: JSON data as a list of dict dates, where the keys are
            the raw market statistics.

    Returns:
        List of floats of price changes between entries in JSON.
    """
    changes = []
    dates = len(json)
    for date in range(1, dates): 
        last_close = json[date - 1]['close']
        now_close = json[date]['close']
        changes.append(now_close - last_close)
    logger.debug('Market Changes (from JSON):\n{0}'.format(changes))
    return changes

def get_gains_losses(changes):
    """ Categorizes changes into gains and losses

    Args:
        changes: List of floats of price changes between entries in JSON.

    Returns:
        Dict of changes with keys 'gains' and 'losses'.
        All values are positive.
    """
    res = {'gains': [], 'losses': []}
    for change in changes:
        if change > 0:
            res['gains'].append(change)
        else:
            res['losses'].append(change * -1)
    logger.debug('Gains: {0}'.format(res['gains']))
    logger.debug('Losses: {0}'.format(res['losses']))
    return res

def get_attribute(json, attr):
    """ Gets the values of an attribute from JSON

    Args:
        json: JSON data as a list of dict dates, where the keys are
            the raw market statistics.
        attr: String of attribute in JSON file to collect.

    Returns:
        List of values of specified attribute from JSON
    """
    res = [json[entry][attr] for entry, _ in enumerate(json)]
    logger.debug('{0}s (from JSON):\n{1}'.format(attr, res))
    return res

def get_json_shift(year, month, day, unit, count, period, symbol):
    """ Gets JSON from shifted date by the Poloniex API

    Args:
        year: Int between 1 and 9999.
        month: Int between 1 and 12.
        day: Int between 1 and 31.
        unit: String of time period unit for count argument.
            How far back to check historical market data.
            Valid values: 'hour', 'day', 'week', 'month', 'year'
        count: Int of units.
            How far back to check historical market data.
        period: Int defining width of each chart candlestick in seconds.
        symbol: String of currency pair, like a ticker symbol.

    Returns: JSON, list of dates where each entry is a dict of raw market data.
    """
    epochs = date.get_end_start_epochs(year, month, day, 'last', unit, count)
    return chart_json(epochs['shifted'], epochs['initial'],
                      period, symbol)[0]
```

The issue was with Poloniex api, and I searched many sources for the resolution but could not find anything working. For example, some say that changing IP or using VNP will help but it isn't. Second I tried using the dedicated server, still the issue persists.

Kindly, suggest me what is the best possible technique available for resolving my issue.

Is there a way to get rid of the Google captcha while requesting through requests library? I guess that is the issue.

Comment: It seems like `.json()` failed to decode the response, propably not recieved json data.

Comment: @t.m.adam Yes this might be the problem. But this is because of the response from the API. The API might be sending the error in the form other than json. Kindly help me.

Comment: Do some debugging maybe? In `chart_json` function, can you print the `.status_code` and `.text` of the response?

Comment: @t.m.adam status what I got is 403.